# How to click on a link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to click on next link on a html page but having difficulties.

I have to get elementbyclassname of the main div and clicking on the second element of the div, here is the HTML of page i want to click:

```html
<div class="next-previous">
            <a href="http://website.net/560339/1/">Previous </a>    
     <a href="http://website.net/560339/2/">Next</a>        
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript what I have tried so far.

```js
var nextlink = document.getElementsByClassName('next-previous');
nextlink[0].click();
```

Comment: Doesn't this click on the `<div>` instead of the children `<a>`s? Do a `.children[0]` to get the top anchor.

Comment: That's what I'm confused in. i'm unable to find that `<a>`

Comment: That's still not working.

`var nextlink = document.getElementsByClassName('next-previous');
nextlink.children[0].click();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're clicking on the `div`, which has no effect. You need to click on the `a`.
Replace `nextlink[0].click()` with `nextlink[0].lastElementChild.click()` and it should work.

Demo (replaced link targets with alerts):

```js
var nextlink = document.getElementsByClassName('next-previous');
nextlink[0].lastElementChild.click();
```

```html
<div class="next-previous">
    <a href="javascript:alert('Previous')">Previous </a>    
    <a href="javascript:alert('Next')">Next</a>        
</div>
```

Comment: Still no click performed.

Comment: @CodyMan I find that hard to believe. I added a snippet, please try that.

Comment: U plagerized my answer, please never do that ....or provide some attribution... I am waiting for your edit attribute the ansewr

Comment: @TusharGupta Wouldn't *plagiarism* imply that your answer would be the same as this? When it's not. Difference is the addition of `lastElementChild`. And that this works

Comment: @RGraham You can check the time of the answer and edit compare them

Comment: @TusharGupta No, I didn't! I copied OP's code, added my changes and happened to replace the links with alerts too.

Comment: @TusharGupta you just added inline alerts, the snippet doesn't work.

Comment: @TusharGupta I'm looking at the full history right now and still seeing that one major difference

Comment: @TusharGupta You think you're the only one with the idea to add alerts or what? Besides, I was working on the snippet by the time your answer was posted (but I can't prove that), but most of all, **your answer doesn't work!**

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused. Your question is tagged as jQuery, but you're using Vanilla.JS.

Anyhow:

## jQuery:

```
$("div.next-previous>a:nth-of-type(2)").click()
// clicks on second <a>
```

## Vanilla.JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName('next-previous')[0].children[1].click()
//does the same
//gets an array of elements with the class 'next-previous', takes the first, then takes the second child and clicks on it
```

Comment: `children[0]` would be the "Previous" link, not the "Next" one.

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't realise he was trying to click on the **Next** one.

Comment: exactly! the above code is clicking on previous, by the way when I'm on the first page the previous link isn't available so I need to use something like last child.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could filter using a CSS selector:

```
document.body.querySelector(".next-previous a:nth-child(2)").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

**You may use**

```
$('.next-previous a').trigger('click');
```

**Or even this would work**

```
$('.next-previous').find('a').trigger('click');
```

As I see you have multiple `<a>` tags within the `<div>` so I suggest to apply unique `class` or `id` to each `<a>` tag. This way it will be easier to refer the links in js/jquery **otherwise** you will need to use `ElementChild` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

My humble contribution, blind shot though since your question is not clear:

```js
var clsA = document.querySelectorAll('.cls > a');
clsA[0].addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    var span;
    ev.preventDefault();
    span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = ' allo';
    this.parentNode.appendChild(span);
});
```

```html
<div class="cls">
    <a href="#">here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flow this blog post.I think it will help you to understand why anchor does not click by javascript.
http://blog.stchur.com/2010/01/15/programmatically-clicking-a-link-in-javascript/

Comment: Unfortunately, your link is now bad :( Any chance of a good link?

Answer (score 1):

window.location.href and hyperlink click using JavaScript or trigger using jQuery not working in latest version of browser's like Microsoft Edge and Chrome.
Works well in Edge and Chrome
  `function link_Click() { setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "page.html;"},1); }`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `:nth-child()` to get desired child. like

```
var nextlink = document.document.querySelectorAll('.next-previous:nth-child(2)').click();   // click the second link
```

```js
var nextlink = document.document.querySelectorAll('.next-previous:nth-child(2)').click();
```

```html
<div class="next-previous"> <a href="http://website.net/560339/1/>Previous</a>
 <a href="http://website.net/560339/2/">Next</a> 
</div>
```